# Embedding Azure chatbot webchat channel into SharePoint Online Modern Pages

Tags: sharepoint, botframework

So I've been having this problem where I am trying to embed an Azure Web App Bot WebChat channel into a SharePoint Online Modern Site page. I'm not sure if it should be as straightforward as I think, but I add the "embed" webpart and attempt to add the `iframe` code, however I get the following error:

> We can't show this embedded content because the code seems to be
>   incomplete. Make sure that the embed code includes width, height and a
>   valid address for the src attribute.

The auto-generated embed code is:

```
<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/AzureBotName?s=BOTSECRET' style='min-width: 400px; width: 100%; min-height: 500px;'></iframe>
```

This embed code works in a SharePoint Online classic site, but not modern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be how SharePoint handles the width and height properties. It wants *specific* width and height attributes set as opposed to the style attribute that the bot embed markup creates.

To further explain, you need this:

```
width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

Instead of this:

```
style='min-width: 400px; width: 100%; min-height: 500px;'></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It works in modern SharePoint site also, no need to change the format of width and height.
If you are an admin, you can make changes in site settings.

> Go to the site collection wherever you want to embed code
>   Click on "Gear " icon, select site information, you will be getting a pane where you have to select "View all site settings"
>   At the section of site collection administration, select "HTML field security" and insert the domain, here is "webchat.botframework.com" as per your requirement and add this and click "OK"
>   Once you are embedding that code, your chatbot will appear

Answer (score 0):

I changed the site settings like @maheshwari-bandala explained, but this was not working. I then also changed the code to:

```
<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/MY_BOT?s=MY_SECRET'  style='width: 400px; width: 100%; height: 500px;'></iframe>
```

This worked! So note it's not `width = "100%"` (like Dana V explained) but `width: 100%`