# Issue when trying to add Microsoft QNA Maker Bot in Sharepoint

Tags: azure, iframe, sharepoint, azure-qna-maker

I have followed the process to create a QNA Maker Web App Bot in Azure that works when I use the Test in Web Chat function. When I try to add the details of the Web Channel into a Webpart Embed area I get the following error

"We can't show this embedded content because the code seems to be incomplete. Make sure that the embed code includes width, height and a valid address for the src attribute."

I have tried two different ways of entering the iframe details and they both come up with the same error.

This is the code that is produced within the bot for the Web Channel

Comment: This has to do with html field security. See this question and two options here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234328/embedding-azure-chatbot-webchat-channel-into-sharepoint-online-modern-pages/53271978#53271978

Comment: Dana, Thank you for that information it was perfect and has now resolved my issue.